# How can I solve "Cannot read property 'define' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, undefined, typeerror

In my project I have defined Models using sequelize for data present in Postgresql. I am getting `Uncaught Error:  Cannot read property 'define' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined`.

I tried adding `var Sequelize = require('sequelize');` but that did not work

How can I resolve this error?

Models

```
module.exports = {
    Customer_data: (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        const Customer_data = sequelize.define('Customer_data', {
            termkey: {
                type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            
        }
        
        return Customer_data;
    }}
```

Customer_data is being called in routes file

routes.js file

```
const NewFile= require("../db/newFile"),
      newFile= new NewFile(config.db.release.dataset);

const { sequelize } = newFile;
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { Customer_data} = require('../db/Models');
const customer_data= Customer_data(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

newFile.js

```
const { db: { release: { color: color1, color2} }, sequelize: conf }
      = require("config"),
      { Sequelize, Op, NumberTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = NewFile;
class NewFile{
   //code
}
```

Comment: It means that `sequelize` is `undefined` and so it doesn't have a `define` property.  How is `Customer_data` being called?

Comment: And why do you declare a constant named `Customer_data` inside of a function called `Customer_data`?

Comment: I edited my qs, can you please check

Comment: how are you calling `Customer_data`?

Comment: As well as `Sequelize` (capital S, the class), do you have a line `const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionString);` (lower case s, the object)? https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#connecting-to-a-database

Comment: @ScottMarcus There is absolutely NO problem declaring a variable inside a function with the same name as the function -- not to mention it's completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Dexygen I didn't say that there was, other than it leads to confusion and possibly bugs, so is not a great idea. That's why it's relevant to ask.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Don't be so literal -- you ABSOLUTELY suggested it was some kind of problem, if not in so many words  Now you're "moving the goalposts" by adding the possibility that it could lead to confusion.

Comment: I have added more details, I hope its more clear now

Comment: @Dexygen Relax. I asked a question. I did not make any suggestions at all about it. I wanted to know because, while legal, it could also be an issue if the local scoped variable hides a higher scoped one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably create a new sequelize object by passing database, user, password, options in the constructor.

```
constructor(conn){
sequelize = new Sequelize(conn.db,conn.user,conn.password,conn.options); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means `sequelize` is undefined as passed to your function. You are `require()`ing as `Sequelize`, but passing `sequelize`.

Comment: I have added more details, I hope its more clear now

Comment: Where is `NewFile` defined in `newFile.js`?

Comment: Its a class in newFile.js

Comment: And is `define` a method on that class?

Comment: No that is how you define a Model - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html

Comment: The `sequelize` parameter being passed is `(new NewFile()).sequelize`. Are you sure that `NewFile` has an instance property `sequelize`?